# Magento2 Unable to serialize value string is corrupted while upgrading magneto version 2.1.8 to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

While upgrading Magento version from 2.1.8 to 2.2.3 I have an issue.

The issue arises when I run command setup:upgrade. It will complete half of way Module 'Magento_Quote':

> Error converting field `value` in table `quote_item_option` where `option_id`=56822 using Magento\Framework\DB\DataConverter\SerializedToJson.
>   Fix data or replace with a valid value.
>   Failure reason: 'Unable to unserialize value, string is corrupted.'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unable to unserialize Issue arises because of Redis Cache

You Need to Run following Command:

```
Redis-cli > FLUSHALL
```